# Oracle show min(), max() in one query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table ----
Works(employer_name,employee_name,salary)

I want the result to show the min and max salary group by each employer, please see below.

**Works**

```
Employer Employee Max Min
A        B        Y
A        C             Y
N        K        Y    
N        P             Y
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It's not exactly what you asked for, but should do the job just fine :)

```
SELECT w.*,
    (SELECT employee_name FROM works WHERE employer_name = w.Employer AND salary = w.Min AND ROWNUM <= 1) AS EmployeeMin,
    (SELECT employee_name FROM works WHERE employer_name = w.Employer AND salary = w.Max AND ROWNUM <= 1) AS EmployeeMax
FROM (
    SELECT employer_name AS Employer,
        min(salary) AS Min,
        max(salary) AS Max
    FROM works
    GROUP BY Employer
) AS w
```

Comment: Hi Boris, Thanks for your answer! I will try the code.